The length of the curve

Find the length of the curve:
$$\theta = \frac{r}{2} \sqrt{r^2+2}+\ln \left(r+\sqrt{r^2+2}\right),\quad 0 \leq r \leq 2.$$

Is it possible to apply the formula for calculating the length of a curve in polar coordinates? I'm uncertain because the $r$ in the formula $ \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt{r_\theta^2+(r'_\theta)^2} \ d\theta $ is a function of $\theta$

$r'_\theta=1/\theta'_r$ and $d\theta=\theta'_rdr$.

A more comfortable variable (than $\theta$ or $r$) is $\operatorname{arsinh}(r/\sqrt2)$, because $\operatorname{arsinh} t= \ln \left(t + \sqrt{t^2 + 1}\right)$.

@AnneBauval Thus, the integrand will be $\sqrt{\theta^2+(\frac{1}{\theta'^2})}\theta'$?

No, $\sqrt{r^2+\frac{1}{\theta_r'^2}}\theta_r'$, or if you take another integration variable $t$:$$\sqrt{r^2+\frac{r_t'^2}{\theta_t'^2}}\theta_t'=\sqrt{r^2\theta_t'^2+r_t'^2}.$$

Let $t:=\operatorname{arsinh}(r/\sqrt2)$ ($0\le t\le\operatorname{arsinh}\sqrt2$).
Then, $$r=\sqrt2\sinh t,\quad r'_t=\sqrt2\cosh t,$$$$\theta=\sinh t\cosh t+t+\ln\sqrt2,\quad\theta'_t=2\cosh^2t,$$
and the length is
$$\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\sqrt2}\sqrt{r^2\theta_t'^2+r_t'^2}\,dt
$$
$$=\sqrt2\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\sqrt2}(1+2\sinh^2t)\cosh t\,dt
$$
$$=\sqrt2\int_0^{\sqrt2}(1+2s^2)\,ds=\frac{14}3.
$$
